# Long running tasks in Thrift

Tags: rpc, thrift, bidirectional

I plan on using [Apache Thrift](https://thrift.apache.org/) but some calls will be long running/blocking but still require a return value, which would traditionally be returned via callback.

I understand that Thrift [does not support](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2630055/225885) callbacks (has this changed?) so I am thinking about making the function just block until a response is returned. Would this be ok? Will Thrift complain (timeout) if an RPC request takes too long?

They say Thrift wasn't intended for bi-directional communication but it should be easy enough to do with a socket.

Context: I am using Thrift or IPC between two processes locally, therefore there won't be huge load on the server alleviating any concern that long running HTTP requests would overload the server.

Am I missing a solution provided by something else?

Answer (score 1):

> I understand that Thrift does not support callbacks (has this changed?)

No (not supported), and no (not changed).

> some calls will be long running/blocking but still require a return value, which would traditionally be returned via callback.

Yes, if you want to stick with the RPC style of doing things, or are technically limited in that regard.

> so I am thinking about making the function just block until a response is 
>   returned. Would this be ok?

Long running calls are a perfectly legal solution. Even polling could be an option, of course unless you are flooding the server with calls. Depends on what "long" means exactly.

> Will Thrift complain (timeout) if an RPC request takes too long?

You can always initiate a new request after the connection has dropped.

> They say Thrift wasn't intended for bi-directional communication 
>   but it should be easy enough to do with a socket.

In a local setup having both ends acting as client *and* server is indeed possible, and maybe the better option in your case.

In contrast, it's much harder to do that across the [interblag](https://xkcd.com/181/). Therefore, if you have strong plans to extend your solution later into such a scenario, this may create some additional headaches to rewrite the bidi solution into long running calls. If that is not the case, you can safely ignore this paragraph.

Comment: the longest running tasks could be "scanning a network for UDB broadcast messages" could run anywhere from seconds to multiples (10s?) of minutes... Client/Server <-> Client/Server should work though..