# Does apache thrift support function variable as parameter?

Tags: c++, c++11, rpc, thrift, idl

I want to use `FuncType` as the parameter type of `foo` function. Does thrift support this? How to define the type inside `FuncType`?

```
struct FuncType {
  // std::function<std::vector<std::pair<int, int>>(const std::string &)>;
  // how to define here?
}

service WorkerService {
  bool foo(1:FuncType func)
}
```

Comment: How would it work? What would happen if the callee invoked the function?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Callbacks in Thrift Asynchronous Functions?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2554999/callbacks-in-thrift-asynchronous-functions)

Answer (score 1):

Apache Thrift was designed to allow RPC calls *between different platforms and environments*. So passing something like `std::function<int(int)>` just can't be supported: how native function defined in C++ could be transferred to JavaScript and vice versa?

(BTW: even if it was somehow possible, it's generally bad idea, to allow users of server to inject some code into ii - for security reasons).

If you want single function with multiple processing options - create some enum and pass it to that function. Even better - define multiple functions in your service. If you want to really allow user to process sample-by-sample: either return all samples to user and process it accordingly in client, or, if there is too much data to pass via network at once, provide "iterator" service:

```
struct MyPair {
   i32 first;
   i32 second;
}

typedef i32 QueryId;

service MyService {
  QueryId startProcessing();
  MyPair getNextSample(1: QueryId id);
}
```