# Passing Thrift service as argument

Tags: thrift

Is it possible to pass a service as an argument to a method in another service in Thrift?

```
service MyService {
  void foo(1: MyOtherService),
}

service MyOtherService {
  void bar(),
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Callbacks in Thrift Asynchronous Functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2554999/callbacks-in-thrift-asynchronous-functions)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Service isn't Thrift serializable (in other words: no sense to transmit service via network - Your foo function to be executed on remote machine with transmitted arguments).

I think **not**.

What is real goal?
I have intuition You want good OO pattern. 
Is this kind of parametrisation?

Comment: E.g. gRPC/protobuf offers built-in streaming which could be one use case. It can be emulated with Thrift though if you design the API in a suitable way

Comment: The goal was to allow services to be partially implemented in different languages. Services would depend on the signatures of methods, but not their implementations. However, this doesn't seem possible in native Thrift.

Comment: 0. agree signatures!=implementations. 1. Thfit solutions fully can be in mixed languages, BUT ....  2. Every pipe has two ends. I understand You want two (partial) services on the same end work in community for other side. QUESTION: different languages from one world, f.e. Java / ,NET? This will be quite simple